# Sometimes I'm round

Tags: riddle

Sometimes I'm round, sometimes I'm square
But I'm only present on happy occasions
I'm always soft inside and beautiful on the outside
My color variations are limitless to the creative hands
Sadly they always like to cut me and light me with real fire

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Cake.
> Mostly round or square
> Only present on happy occasions
> Decoration on the top with Sponge/Cheese in centre
> Placed candles on top for b'days